# Extra field in custom registration in DRF won't save

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a custom serializer that extends dj_rest_auth's `RegisterSerializer`, added the extra `user_type` field, overrode the `get_cleaned_data` method to include the `user_type` in the cleaned data then configured the custom registration serializer used for registration.

Here's my code:

```py
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    user_type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[('seeker', 'Seeker'), ('recruiter', 'Recruiter')])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        data = super().get_cleaned_data()
        data['user_type'] = self.validated_data.get('user_type', '')
        return data
```

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    class Type(models.TextChoices):
        seeker = "Seeker"
        recruiter = "Recruiter"
    
    base_type = Type.seeker
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=Type.choices, default=base_type, max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "Profiles"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

```py
class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    serializer_class = CustomRegisterSerializer
```

Comment: And? What is happening? You don't give any details of the actual problem here.

Comment: @michjnich the problem is stated in the title

Comment: And you gave zero info about what was actually happening, any trace info etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a piece missing in your code. You've added the `user_type` to the cleaned data but haven't shown how the `Profile` gets created and how the `user_type` is stored in the `Profile` model when a new user registers.

Here's how you can complete the registration process by creating the associated profile:

Override the `save` method in your `CustomRegisterSerializer`.

```py
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    # ... [rest of your code]

    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user_type = self.validated_data.get('user_type')
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, user_type=user_type)
        return user
```

Comment: This made the `user_type` field disappear from the registration fields. weird

Comment: When you override the save method of the serializer, it shouldn't affect the displayed fields in any way. The fields that are displayed are based on the serializer fields you define and shouldn't be affected by the logic within the save method.

Comment: Disregard the comment. I went to the wrong `url`. Now I'm getting a `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_type` you know what's causing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76904746/django-db-utils-integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed-accounts-profile-user

Comment: Do you have the error when you create a new one or update the existed one?

Comment: This is solved thanks

Comment: Always happy to help. <3
Please thumbs up if the answer is useful.

Comment: Can you help me with this aswell? The problem is the link that django-allauth is sending should be the one I created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76905060/dj-rest-auth-templateresponsemixin-requires-either-a-definition-of-template-nam/76905128#76905128