# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having issues with registering a user in my project. I have a custom serializer that inherits from the `RegisterView` of `dj_rest_auth`. My code is:

`views.py`

```py
class ProfileDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        profile = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        

class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    serializer_class = CustomRegisterSerializer
```

`serializer.py`

```py
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    user_type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[('seeker', 'Seeker'), ('recruiter', 'Recruiter')])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        data = super().get_cleaned_data()
        data['user_type'] = self.validated_data.get('user_type', '')
        return data

    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user_type = self.validated_data.get('user_type')
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, user_type=user_type)
        return user
```

`models.py`

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    class Type(models.TextChoices):
        seeker = "Seeker"
        recruiter = "Recruiter"
    
    base_type = Type.seeker
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=Type.choices, default=base_type, max_length=20)
```

`signals.py`

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, user_type='')

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

I expect the code to return a `200` after I perform a `POST` request.

Comment: Did you create a signal?

Comment: I did. Added it to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely defined a signal to create a `Profile`, so when the `User` object is saved, it already creates a `Profile`, so creating a second one for the same user is no longer possible. This is one of many reasons *not* to work with signals.

It thus might be better to just omit the signal, and create the `Profile` where it should be created: in the corresponding view(s) and `ModelAdmin`. If removing the signal is really not possible, you can work with an `.update_or_create` call instead:

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    user_type = serializers.ChoiceField(
        choices=[('seeker', 'Seeker'), ('recruiter', 'Recruiter')]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        data = super().get_cleaned_data()
        data['user_type'] = self.validated_data.get('user_type', '')
        return data

    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        defaults = {'user_type': self.validated_data.get('user_type')}
        Profile.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user, defaults=defaults, create_defaults=defaults
        )
        return user
```

Comment: I removed the signal which worked. Thanks!