# dj-rest-auth TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

I'm using `dj_rest_auth` for authentication and when I click on the verify email link, this error comes out [image]

I overriden the `ConfirmEmailView` of `django-allauth` but still getting the error
My views are:

```py
class CustomConfirmEmailView(ConfirmEmailView):
    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass **`template_name`**

```
class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    serializer_class = CustomRegisterSerializer
    template_name = 'path/to/filename.html'
    success_url = '/url_name/'
```

Comment: That's done but I need it to redirect to the correct `url` when the user clicks it on their email. It redirects to the default `url` given by `dj-rest-auth`.